# How do I convert a string of the form %programfiles%\directory\tool.exe to a useable Filename in C#/.net?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have an application which takes a string value of the form **%programfiles%\directory\tool.exe** from its application config file.

I want to make this into a useable filename so that I can call

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filename)
```

and have it execute the application. I'm curently getting a **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception - The system cannot find the file specified**

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
filename = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(filename);
```